# How to channel Redstone current vertically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm making a door with piston sliding sideways that reacts to pressure plates.
As the pressure plates are sending the current to redstone at a very low level, I need to raise it somehow, and this leads to awkward stairs of redstone.

[image: Screenshot of my contraption]

So I'm wondering whether there are better ways of sending the redstone current up, maybe even vertically.

Comment: There are many [piston door](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=piston+door) tutorials out there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can place redstone dust on glowstone **and upside-down slabs**. This is important because they are also transparent blocks, so the redstone current won't be blocked. You can set up your glowstone or top slabs in an alternating pattern, with redstone on top, and then run the current from there.

[image: A column of upside-down slabs. (www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/File:Upside-downRedstone.png)]

And here is a video by CaptainSparklez that demonstrates this:

Comment: In important note about this is that the redstone current will only travel upwards. It will not travel downwards.

Answer (score 34):

Going straight up is one of the easier directions to manage via redstone.

[image]

Just alternate torches and solid blocks, and you can send the signal up as far as you need.

Comment: It's so much more compact now. Thanks! P.S. **[Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aVxqF.png)** is a screenshot of how it looks now in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 18):

In this specific case with powering two vertically stacked pistons, you can use the Redstone Torch stacking technique, and it works out nicely. The torch adjacent to the bottom piston powers it, and also powers the block above it, powering the top piston as well. Conveniently, there's no need to invert your input because of the even number of torches used for the vertical signal transmission.

[image]

Comment: This is very convenient, but the other answer appeared sooner... And I'm using one torch, not 3, anyway.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Yeah, I saw your screenshot – probably better than mine since you moved the signal upwards before using the torches.

Comment: You can extend this to three blocks high by placing a redstone dust on the block above the piston.

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone needs to go down instead of up, I've found that having an upside-down sticky piston pushing a block of redstone works quite well. You could create a chain of these to go very far down perfectly vertically.

Comment: Any way to do this when there are several redstone signals right next to each other? I haven't found a way to prevent them from interfering with each other.